# How to dump thread stacks

Tags: c, linux, x86

I want to dump the stacks of the threads in a file. How can I do that in linux? How can I find the starting address of the stack and its size? Note that I want to do this progammatically from the same process (not using ptrace, gdb or something like that).

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger?

Comment: I want to do it programmatically, not using a debugger.

Comment: Do you want to get the callstack, or just a dump of all of the stack?

Comment: @Pileborg, just dump the stack.

Comment: If you are using GCC, there might be some internal functions to get the stack pointer, otherwise you can find the address of the stack in a file in the `/proc/self/` directory.

Answer (score 2):

if you use the gnu c lib, you can use the backtrace() function

http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Backtraces.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the **pthread_attr_getstack** function; this yields the thread's stack address and size.

Comment: This won't do the job. If the thread is using a system-allocated stack, `pthread_attr_getstack` will return address and size 0.

Comment: @MetallicPriest That would work I suppose, but it is by definition non-portable :-). That may not matter, depending on the OP's need.

Comment: But on my system, which is Ubunutu 10 64 bit, pthread_attr_t has a strange definition, which is different from what it should be,         typedef union
{
  char __size[__SIZEOF_PTHREAD_ATTR_T];
  long int __align;
} pthread_attr_t;

Comment: @denniston.t, you're right. I think it's the same on Solaris, and probably other Unixen. Can it be relied upon if the thread has a user-defined stack?

Comment: @BrettHale: Well, if the thread stack is user-defined, it means your application already has all the information needed because your application allocated the stack. Meaning you don't need to call that function anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use `gdb` to attach to a running process via its PID (process ID):

```
gdb -p 1234
```

And then type `bt` to get a backtrace.

Comment: Don't want to use gdb, I want to do it from my program

Answer (score 1):

Glibc has function called backtrace which does what you want.

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_665.html

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6391?page=0,0

Last time I tried it, results were less than perfect, but somewhat useful.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

**Why** do you want to **dump your threads' stacks??**

Do you want to get some [application checkpointing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing) ? If you want it, there are some libraries implementing it, even imperfectly, but usefully in practice.

The point is, that even if you manage to dump your threads' stacks in a file, I'm not sure you'll be able to do somehing useful with that file. You won't even be able to restart your application using these stacks, because when restarted (even in the same configuration) the stacks might be located elsewhere (because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)), unless you write a 0 digit into `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`

I heard there is also some linux libraries which force a running process to dump a core file (that you could examine with `gdb` later) without aborting that process.

A call stack is something very brittle, and you cannot re-use it without precautions.

If you just want to *inspect* your call stack, look into Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace).

Notice that several checkpointing infrastructures (including [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/)'s [`save-lisp-and-die`](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Saving-a-Core-Image)) are not capable of restoring any other threads than the main one. That says something about the difficulty of managing `pthread`-s stacks.

Comment: Yes, basically for checkpointing. One idea I had in my mind is to use pthread_attr_setstack to set stacks and then fork a process as a checkpoint. But since all the threads other than who called fork die, I wanted to recreate the threads and copy the stacks from dead threads. However, I still need to to know how to get the CPU registers for the dead threads.

Comment: Then I suggest using (and perhaps improving) existing checkpoint infrastructures. As usual, the devil is in the details.

Comment: Can you kindly point towards some open source checkpointing infrastructures. I will be grateful.

Comment: The wikipage under http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing contains some links to free software checkpointing libraries